# Are there any cards in Yu-Gi-Oh that let me interact with face-down banished cards?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

Pot of Desires is a card where you banish 10 cards from the top your deck, face-down to draw 2 cards. Is there anyway I can change those cards, like flipping them face-up or returning them to the Graveyard?

Comment: Actually, the card you mention is Pot of Desires

Comment: Oops,sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few cards that allow you to put these back in the graveyard or deck.
E.g. "Psyframelord Omega" and "Necroface".

The rule around this is that you cannot use cards that limit you to a certain card type (for example 'escape from the different dimension' can only summon back a monster).
The cards I gave as an example do not have these limitations but can put back any type of card, so they still work with face down cards.
Of note is, you yourself can still look at these cards, so you do not have to pick them blindly to put back in the graveyard/deck